# Updating Windows Tablet Applications

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, mobile, tablet

I'm an experienced Windows Desktop developer trying to wrap my head around Windows 10 and the new universal and mobile applications.
 I'm considering writing a windows tablet app for my company and I want to see if there is a way to have it work the way we need it to.

Here are the requirements:
 The app would only run on a few select windows tablets own by the company.
 The app would send information back to a central server and receive data from that same server.
 The app would need to be updated periodically.

In addition to whether the above is easily possible I need to know:
 Would I be able to install this app manually (not through the Windows Store) or alternatively could I put it on the windows store and have it only able to be downloaded to those few selected devices?
 Would I be able to update the app remotely (either by forcing the update or by allowing the user to install the update). This would be to avoid having to bring in all the devices in order to patch the app.

Any recommendations as to how to implement this or where to look for information would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps are update-able so you do not need to worry about this. For Windows Store apps / Universal apps you have several deployment options. The public store is only one of them. You could side-load your app, that might - depending on the number of devices - be a lot of work.

Alternatively you can use a central deployment server and connect your phone / device to this server using a company account. Software is for example [Microsoft Intune](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/microsoft-intune/) or [Microsoft System Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/system-center-2012-r2/).

You can find a Channel9 video outlining options for enterprises here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3306